# Error in mongodb query to get movie based on id

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.movmodels.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55320b0e0e9e0d9d0540593c"),
    "username" : "punk",
    "favMovies" : [
        {
            "alternate_ids" : {
                "imdb" : "0137523"
            },
            "abridged_cast" : [
                {
                    "characters" : [
                        "Tyler"
                    ],
                    "id" : "162652627",
                    "name" : "Brad Pitt"
                },
                {
                    "characters" : [
                        "Narrator"
                    ],
                    "id" : "162660884",
                    "name" : "Edward Norton"
                },
                {
                    "characters" : [
                        "Robert"
                    ],
                    "id" : "162676383",
                    "name" : "Meat Loaf"
                },
                {
                    "characters" : [
                        "Angel Face"
                    ],
                    "id" : "162653925",
                    "name" : "Jared Leto"
                },
                {
                    "characters" : [
                        "Boss"
                    ],
                    "id" : "770706064",
                    "name" : "Zach Grenier"
                }
            ],
            "synopsis" : "",
            "ratings" : {
                "audience_score" : 96,
                "audience_rating" : "Upright",
                "critics_score" : 80,
                "critics_rating" : "Certified Fresh"
            },
            "release_dates" : {
                "dvd" : "2000-06-06",
                "theater" : "1999-10-15"
            },
            "critics_consensus" : "",
            "runtime" : 139,
            "mpaa_rating" : "R",
            "year" : 1999,
            "title" : "Fight Club",
            **"id" : "13153"**
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is my data in mongodb.
As I am new to mongodb I wanted to know query to get movie with a particular id.
The query that I tried is. I need to get the movie based on id so that I can remove it from my database

```
db.movmodels.findOne({username:"punk"},{favMovies:{id:13153}})
```

but this gives me error.

```
2015-04-18T05:41:26.221-0400 E QUERY    Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue ported projection option: favMovies: { id: 13153.0 }",
    "code" : 17287
}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DBQuery.next (src/mongo/shell/query.js:259:15)
    at DBCollection.findOne (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:188:22)
    at (shell):1:14 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:259
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your query:

The second parameter to [`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) is a *projection*, not part of the query. What you want is to supply *one* document for the query that has two properties: `{"username" : "punk", favMovies : { ... } }`

However, you also don't want to compare the entire sub-document `favMovies`, but you only want to match on *one of its properties*, the `id`, which requires to 'reach into the object' using the dot operator: `{username:"punk", "favMovies.id" : 13153}`.

However, that will probably not work yet, because `13153` is not the same as `"13153"`, the latter being a string while the former is a number in JSON.

```
db.movmodels.findOne({username:"punk", "favMovies.id" : "13153"})
```

Keep in mind, however, that this will find the entire document for the user named "punk". I'm not sure what exactly your data structure should look like, but it appears you'll have to `$pull` the movie from the user. In general, I'd say you're embedding too much data into the user, but that's hard to tell without knowing the exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

If you just wanted to get first user who has this fav movie:

```
db.movmodels.findOne({"favMovies.id": 13153});
```

And, if you want to know if that user has that movie as favorite.

```
db.movmodels.findOne({"favMovies.id": 13153, username:"punk"});
```

Second argument in the findOne is used to only return particular field.

Comment: Changing the order of constraints in the query might hurt performance. Let's assume there are many users that like a particular movie, but user names are unique. Then, even if `favMovies.id` is indexed, the first query criterion still leaves thousands of matches that must be found in the index before being filtered by the (presumably unique) user name. As a general rule, try to order query parameters in descending selectivity order.

Comment: Thank you @mnemosyn for response and clarification. We are already using indexes and improving more on it. I didn't get your last line: *try to order query parameters in descending selectivity order*. Will you please elaborate it a bit.

Comment: I think that means that you should put first the query parameters that are more selective, thus in the next query parameters you will search between less results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [`$elemMatch` projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) (not to be confused with the `$elemMatch` query operator)

```
db.movmodels.find({username:"punk"},{favMovies:{$elemMatch:{id:"13153"}}});
```

`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find a movie that has another movie (with id 13153) in 'favMovies' array, then write the query as below:

```
db.movmodels.findOne({username:"punk",'favMovies.id':13153})
```

And if you want to find a movie with _id 55320b0e0e9e0d9d0540593cwrite the following query:

```
db.movmodels.findOne({username:"punk",'_id':ObjectId("55320b0e0e9e0d9d0540593c")})
```

Comment: db.movmodels.findOne({username:"punk"},{'favMovies.id':13153})
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("55320b0e0e9e0d9d0540593c"),
 "favMovies" : [
  {
   "id" : "13153"
  }
 ]
}   I am getting the data but I want to use this to delete data from my mongodb for which I wrote this code in nodejs server app.delete('/favMovies/:user/:movid',function(req, res){
 var u = req.params.user;
 var mid = req.params.movid;
 MovModel.findOne({username:u},{'favMovies.id':mid}, function (err, doc) {
 doc.remove();
    MovModel.find(function (err, data) {
    
     res.json(data);
    });
 });
});

Comment: If you are getting the parameter from query string (e.g. using req.params.user), you should convert it to integer:
var id = parseInt(mid);
and then use id in your query, mid.